# How to modify CSS style with JHipster?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jhipster

This may seem like a silly question for front end developers, but how do you modify the CSS stylesheets in JHipster? With Gulp, Nodejs, Bower, Boostrap, Sass, Gradle/Maven and Compass all intermingled, some pointers to get started would be appreciated. I'm using Gradle.

Of course, simply modifying src/main/scss/main.scss, doesn't seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1. Install gulp - see: https://gist.github.com/aaronwaldon/8657432 and
   any missing npm dependencies not mentioned in the article (if gulp fails in #3 below).
2. Edit src/main/scss/main.scss as required.
3. Then, in the project root (where gulpfile.js is), and run gulp - for my configuration, we're using Compass, so the "gulp compass" command updated the css.

Comment: There is also a `gulp watch` command which will automatically recompile CSS once any changes are made to any `*.scss` file under `src/main/scss/`

Comment: How this is working? I generated my app whit Sass and if I check my css in browser's devtool it seems that it is using assets/styles/main.css. If I edit that file I can see the changes immediately. BUT when I build my app again with mvn, my changes lost every time. How this is working and what file should I change that those changes are permanent.

Comment: This is likely VERY outdated. The original answer was more than a year and many versions ago.